# Case class (with companion object) in method declaration evaluated as Any

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an issue with a case class + companion object and (possibly) its interaction with Play. Whenever i try to pass it as an argument for a method, it is interpreted as being of type `any` instead of `EventList`. Using it in a method body works perfectly, however.

I can't seem to understand why. Below is a simplified segment of the code in question (it comes from a large code base).

EventList.scala:

```
package v1.objects

final case class EventList( ... ) {
   ...
}

object EventList {
  def apply( ... ): EventList = {
    ...
    new EventList( ... )
  }
}
```

ObjectRepository.scala:

```
package v1.objects

class ObjectExecutionContext @Inject()(actorSystem: ActorSystem) extends CustomExecutionContext(actorSystem, "repository.dispatcher")

trait ObjectRepository {
  def patch(newEvents: EventList)(implicit mc: MarkerContext): Future[Int]
  ...
}

@Singleton
class ObjectRepositoryImpl @Inject()()(implicit ec: ObjectExecutionContext) extends ObjectRepository {
  override def patch(newEvents: EventList)(implicit mc: MarkerContext): Future[Int] = {
    ...
    var eventList = EventList(...) // Retreive the old events from DB, works fine
    eventList = EventList(eventList.underlying :+ newEvents.underlying) // <- This fails! newEvents has type Any
    ...
  }
}
```

The error message on compilation:

```
Error: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
(underlying: List[v1.objects.Event])v1.objects.EventList 
<and>
(doc: org.mongodb.scala.Document)v1.objects.EventList
cannot be applied to (String, List[Object])
eventList = EventList(eventList.underlying :+ newEvents.underlying)
```

Comment: You should include the full declarations of the case class arguments and the `apply` method arguments, without that it is quite hard to guess why it does not work.

Comment: `:+` adds one element to a list. You probably intended to use `++` to combine two lists together. Other than that, more info is needed.

Comment: The case class arguments and the apply method arguments all work as expected, and they work fine in the method bodies. The problem is that the compiler ignores the type in the method declaration and treats it as `Any`. 

Thanks Oleg, I simplified a for loop and forgot to make that change :)

Comment: If I include the full declarations then I break non-disclosure clauses on my contract. I've heavily modified this example code to cover the gist of the problem without revealing anything about the actual problem, but I can try to construct a minimal breaking example and upload it to github. I was hoping that it perhaps was some fundamental flaw in my usage of case classes with object companions and their interaction with singletons in play (or perhaps in method arguments in general) that would easily be identified by someone with more knowledge on Scala/Play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This creates a List of Any:

```
eventList.underlying :+ newEvents.underlying
```

This adds a List as an Element to the existing List.

And the common `Super-Type` is then `Any`.

What you need is the function that adds a List to another List > this returns a List of their contents:

```
eventList.underlying ++ newEvents.underlying
```

The exact syntax depends on the `underlying` type.

**Example:**

```
case class EventList(underlying: Seq[String]) 

val el1 = EventList(Seq("e1", "e2"))
val el2 = EventList(Seq("e4", "e5"))

println(el1.underlying :+ el2.underlying) // List(e1, e2, List(e4, e5))

println(el1.underlying ++ el2.underlying) // List(e1, e2, e4, e5)
```